# sessionStorage in Safari 14.1.1 lost if I edit the URL to change route and don't open the Developer Tool

Tags: safari, session-storage

Description:

- After update Safari to version 14.1.1. The sessionStorage does not persist if navigate to any route in the same website by editting the URL in address bar.
- Screen recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvEclwHl8zY

Step to reproduce:

- Open any website. Ex: https://google.com
- Open Developer Tool, type “sessionStorage.setItem(‘test’, 10)” and Enter
- Open Storage tab and check the above item has been added to Session Storage
- Close Developer Tool
- Edit the URL in the address bar and press enter. Ex: https://www.google.com/imghp
- Open Developer Tool again and open Storage tab and check Session Storage Item with key “test”

Expected result:

- Session Storage Item with key “test” exist and has value 10

Actual result:

- Session Storage item with key “test” doesn’t exist

Note: The funny thing that everything work fine if i keep Developer Tool opened for the whole steps

Comment: I am observing the same weird behavior. IMHO, it's more like a bug than a feature. Hope someone could explain.

Comment: I know this is a long shot but - did you ever find a solution? I'm experiencing the same in Safari 15.2. Works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: yes same behaviour for me as well is there any workaround

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue in Safari 16.0

Comment: Still facing same issue in 16.4